# regex for initials separated by commas?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that can be used to verify if a string contains only initials, then followed by commas if there is more than one initial.

This is the best I've managed to do:
`"^([A-Za-z],[A-Za-z],[A-Za-z])$"`
by replacing all spaces with `""`.

An example of an allowed string would be `a, b, c, d,           f,      g`

while one that wouldn't pass would be `a, b,  c, df, e`

This only works for exactly 3 initials, so I was wondering how I could get it to work with more or less initials while also not letting any outliers through.

Edit:
`^([A-Za-z],([A-Za-z],)*[A-Za-z])$"` seems to work quite well, but how would I change this code to work for just 1 character (since I need the last character, which usually doesn't have a comma following it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

```
^[A-Za-z](?:,\s+[A-Za-z])*$
```

This matches a single character/initial, then followed by zero or more commas followed by whitespace and another initial.

### Demo

Comment: Seems to have done the trick, just modified it a bit because I was trimming out spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match for initials, it doesn't look at commas, just initials and matches multiple found:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])
```